# Execute custom SQL in symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to execute some custom SQL to retrieve some model objects in a Symfony application. I found a tutorial on the web that said something like this would allow me to execute the query although not populate the models (populating the model isn't a major issue, it's just for read only data).

```
$pdo = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->connection()->getDbh();
$pdo->prepare("SELECT * from something complicated");
$pdo->execute();
$this->sensorReadings = $pdo->fetchAll();
```

But I'm getting an error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute()
in sfproject/apps/frontend/modules/site/actions/actions.class.php
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * from something complicated";
$rs = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->fetchAssoc($query);
```

The resultset is an array.

Answer (score 2):

```
// get Doctrine_Connection object
$con = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->connection();
// execute SQL query, receive Doctrine_Connection_Statement
$st = $con->execute("SELECT User.* FROM ....");
// fetch query result
$result = $st->fetchAll();

// convert array to objects
foreach ($result as $userArray) {
    $user = new User();
    $user->fromArray($userArray);
    ...
}
```

This code is not very short but allows to execute custom query via existing Doctrine connection and receive your object in the end.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your question (this is done from a task):**

```
$databaseManager = new sfDatabaseManager ( $this->configuration );
Doctrine_Manager::connection ()->setAttribute ( Doctrine_Core::ATTR_AUTO_FREE_QUERY_OBJECTS, true );

$dbOptions = Doctrine_Manager::connection ()->getManager ()->getConnection ( 'doctrine' )->getOptions ();
$dbDsn = $dbOptions['dsn'];
$dbDsnArr = explode ( ';', $dbDsn );
$dbHost = str_replace ( 'mysql:host=', '', $dbDsnArr[0] );
$dbName = str_replace ( 'dbname=', '', $dbDsnArr[1] );
$dbUn = $dbOptions['username'];
$dbPw = $dbOptions['password'];
```

**Assuming the DSN is configured as such:
dsn: 'mysql:host=somedomain;dbname=dbname'**

This code allows you to retrieve the database connection information of any connection, so it will work for multiple connections as well

I hope this helps...