# how to write custom query in symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1

I am using symfony framework for my project, but many time i'm very confused to write mysql query in doctrine mode, so, please suggest me how to write custom query in symfony,
like

```
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE A.ID = 'X3B8882'
```

Comment: Your answer is given at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324960/execute-custom-sql-in-symfony

Comment: Are you talking about Symfony-2.0 or any previous versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM USER WHERE A.ID = 'X3B8882'"    

$conn = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->connection();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $results[] = $row['sm_mnuitem_webpage_url'] ;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your sql is invalid, but assuming `A` is a reference to the user table:

```
$user = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->from("User a")
  ->where("a.id = ?", "X3B8882")
  ->fetchOne();
```

or alternatively

```
$user = UserTable::getInstance()->findOneById("X3B8882");
```

This is one of the most basic queries, so I highly recommend you read the documentation available on doctrine's homepage.